# is upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 lead to data loss?

Tags: upgrade

i want to know that if i upgrade my system from 13.04 to 13.10.Is there any chance of data loss(music,documents,video etc.) after upgradation?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problems. Your personal data will stay untouched. But it is a good idea to create backups from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You should always back up your system, but with that being said the answer is most likely not.

It is hard to say with 100% certainty because things do happen like power outage or drive failure.

I upgraded just fine though.